# Flask Application - Error deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy my Flask application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However, I am running into this issue / error that doesn't seem to step from application code I wrote but from one of the libraries.

```
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Aug  7 00:19:43 ip-172-31-27-51 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Aug  7 00:19:43 ip-172-31-27-51 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Aug  7 00:19:43 ip-172-31-27-51 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Aug  7 00:19:43 ip-172-31-27-51 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Aug  7 00:19:43 ip-172-31-27-51 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Aug  7 00:19:43 ip-172-31-27-51 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

I found the error on `AWS EC2` instance logs.

Here's my file structure:

```
- auth
  * login
  * server
  * init.py

  - templates
    * base.html

- pages
  * home.py
  * page2.py 

index.py
app.py
```

contents of `app.py`

```
import dash
import flask

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
                          external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,
               )

server = app.server
```

contents of `index.py`

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # header
    html.Div([
        
        dcc.Link(
            href=get_relative_path('/home'),
        ),

        dcc.Link(
            href=get_relative_path('/archive'),
        ),

        dcc.Location(id='url'),

        html.Div(id='page-content', style={'margin-left': '2%'}),

])



# Render page content
@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"),
              [
                Input('url', 'pathname')
              ]
             )
def display_content(pathname):

    if pathname == '/home':
        return home.layout

    elif pathname == '/archive':
        return archive.layout()
        
    else:
        return home.layout
```

contents of `init.py`

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required
from .server import server
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from index import app as dashApp


@server.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/dashboard/')


app = DispatcherMiddleware(server, {
    '/dashboard': dashApp.server,
    #add dash routes
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5000, app, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

contents of `server.py`

```
from flask import Flask

server = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you need `application`?

Comment: The issue was with Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.py` should be cancelled `application.py`. Same for `app` in your code. It should be `application`.

Comment: I have been able to run the app with app.py. Why is it looking for application and application.py?

Comment: @kms because these are default eb settings

Comment: I have been able to run the app successfully before with `app.py` and `app`

Comment: @kms You may have changed default settings before. Your EB clearly looks for `application`: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'".